# access xampp/htdocs from outside

Tags: apache

I installed xampp server in a server and I want to open the projects in htdocs not only from         (http://localhost/folder/file.php)      but from other computers as well, by its ip. example: (192.168.1.210/folder/file.php) how do I do this? I did edit the httd.conf

```
<Directory/>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to allow access in all subdirectories of xampp/htdocs.. but still nothing! I can't open my projects login file unless I'm logged in the server. thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a directory setting but a vhost setting…

Comment: so where should i do the changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a virtual host in Apache, that listens to at least the given IP (`192.168.1.210:80`) or to any IP (`*:80`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/some_app
</VirtualHost>
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Please don't edit the `httpd.conf`, as the changes might get lost on the next software update. You need to create a vHost inside the `site-available` in den XAMPP/Apache folder.

Comment: @Mirela Please read a [tutorial on Apache vHosts](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/) or step into the [Apache documentation on vHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).